# Multiprocessing pool in python spitting out bus 10 error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pool

I'm working on a Google Image Crawler.

I've got page sources, and extracted the parts where `href` is embedded.

The source codes are as below:

```
links = soup.find_all("a", class_="rg_l")
try:
    pool = Pool(8)
    pool.map(web_crawl.download_image, links)
finally:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

My attempt was to pass each element of the links(which is list) to `download_image` function and request for the image by http protocol.
But it keeps spitting out a Bus 10 error. Any advice would be appreciated.

(I've checked that pool.map() is causing this error)

`download_image` function looks like this:

```
def download_image(link):
    ua = UserAgent()
    headers = {"User-Agent": ua.random}

    # Get the image link
    try:
        r = requests.get("https://www.google.com" + link.get("href"), headers=headers)
    except:
        print("Cannot get link.")

    title = str(fromstring(r.content).findtext(".//title"))
    links = title.split(" ")[-1]

    # Download the image
    print("At : " + os.getcwd() + ", Downloading from " + links)
    try:
        if links.split(".")[-1] == ('jpg' or 'png' or 'jpeg'):
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(links, links.split("/")[-1])
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: I don't recognize "Bus 10" as a type of error that could possibly be raised by Python. Are you getting a traceback? How are you running your program, and how does that error appear?

Comment: I just ran it on my terminal, and it just spits out 'Bus error: 10' literally.